# ¿como crear una tabla en la que la casilla de total sume automaticamente al insertar nuevas cantidades?

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo javascript y me ha surgido una duda con respecto a un ejercio.
La cuestion es que me pedian una tabla con un sumatorio, cosa que ya he logrado pero quiero que sume automaticamente, no al pulsar el boton actualizar.

les dejo el codigo que hice.

```
document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = sumaIngresos();
function sumaIngresos() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("A2").value);

  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("A3").value);

  c = a + b;

  return c;
}

`document.getElementById("totalB").innerHTML = sumaGastos();

function sumaGastos() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("B2").value);

  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("B3").value);

  z = x + y;
  return z;
}
```

y aqui el html

```
'<body>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Ingresos</th>
    <th>Gastos</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="A2" id="A2" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="B2" id="B2" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="A3" id="A3" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="B3" id="B3" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="total" colspan="2">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="total" id="totalA"></td>
    <td class="total" id="totalB"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input
  class="btn btn-primary"
  type="button"
  value="Actualizar"
  onclick="location.reload()"
/>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

'

Se me ha ocurrido poner un evento "onchange" pero no consigo implementarlo correctamente.

Gracias.

Comment: *pero quiero que sume automaticamente*. Y cómo agregas los rows a la tabla?

Comment: No, lo que necesito es que en le rows que ya hay, al cambir el input sume automaticamente. Lo que tu me planteas es un problema que intentaré resolver mas adelnte.

Comment: Dijiste que se te ocurrió poner un evento 'onChage'. Qué has intentado? Por favor copia y pega ese código para que podamos revisarlo.

Comment: Pues seria algo asi al principio del código:    
    document.getElementById("A2").addEventListener("onchange", 
    sumaIngresos());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay diferentes formas de hacerlo. Partiendo de tu código, algo como esto funciona:

```js
document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = sumaIngresos();

function sumaIngresos() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("A2").value);
  a = a || 0;

  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("A3").value);
  b = b || 0
  c = a + b;

  return c;
}

document.getElementById("totalB").innerHTML = sumaGastos();

function sumaGastos() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("B2").value);
  x = x || 0;
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("B3").value);
  y = y || 0;
  z = x + y;
  return z;
}

var ingresos = document.querySelectorAll('.ingresos');
ingresos.forEach(campo => {
  campo.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log('updated')
    document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = sumaIngresos();
  })
});

var gastos = document.querySelectorAll('.gastos');
gastos.forEach(campo => {
  campo.addEventListener('change', function() {

    document.getElementById("totalB").innerHTML = sumaGastos();
  })
});
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Ingresos</th>
    <th>Gastos</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="A2" id="A2" class="ingresos" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="B2" id="B2" class="gastos" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="A3" id="A3" class="ingresos" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="B3" id="B3" class="gastos" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th class="total" colspan="2">total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="total" id="totalA"></td>
    <td class="total" id="totalB"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input
  class="btn btn-primary"
  type="button"
  value="Actualizar"
  onclick="location.reload()"
/>
```

EDIT: Com aporte a la respuesta, también se puede hacer que el evento en ves de surgir cuando se desenfoque el input, se de en tiempo real haciendo el llamado al input en vez del change, como lo mostraré a continuación:

```js
function sumaIngresos() {
  // Se reemplaza el parseInt por el Number, con la idea de poder usar números con decimales
  var a = Number(document.getElementById("A2").value);
  // Se puede hacer uso de la función isNaN() la cual retorna true si no es un número valido o false si es un número válido
  a = isNaN(a) ? 0 : a;
  var b = Number(document.getElementById("A3").value);
  b = isNaN(b) ? 0 : b;
  c = a + b;

  return c;
}

function sumaGastos() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("B2").value);
  x = isNaN(x) ? 0 : x;
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("B3").value);
  y = isNaN(y) ? 0 : y;
  z = x + y;

  return z;
}
// Haces que se implemente la funcionalidad del js después de que se cargue la vista, para mitigar fallos
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = sumaIngresos();
  document.getElementById("totalB").innerHTML = sumaGastos();
  // Con el querySelectorAll obtienes una lista de elementos de tipo NodeElements
  var ingresos = document.querySelectorAll('.Ingresos');
  ingresos.forEach(campo => {
    campo.addEventListener('input', function() {
      document.getElementById("totalA").innerHTML = sumaIngresos();
    })
  });

  var gastos = document.querySelectorAll('.Gastos');
  gastos.forEach(campo => {
    campo.addEventListener('input', function() {
      document.getElementById("totalB").innerHTML = sumaGastos();
    })
  });
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Ingresos</th>
      <th>Gastos</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="A2" id="A2" class="Ingresos" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="B2" id="B2" class="Gastos" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="A3" id="A3" class="Ingresos" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="B3" id="B3" class="Gastos" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="total" colspan="2">total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="total" id="totalA"></td>
      <td class="total" id="totalB"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Actualizar" onclick="location.reload()" />
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente y además me has hecho comprender algunas cosas que no tenia en cuenta como que aparezca "0" en lugar de nan. Ahora me toca estudiármelo para comprenderlo del todo. Repito, muchas gracias.

Comment: Gracias por el Edit del Input